# SQL Full text search is not working after CLP word

Tags: sql, full-text-search

If I have a table, which has a varchar(max) full text indexed column, and I put the following in the column
'CLP3 365 367', then you cannot search for the 365 or 367.
The containstable(mytable, *, '"365*"') command doesn't give any data.

If I set the field to 'clp3 365 367' everything is fine.
If there is no CLP (upcase) then everything works fine. The database is case insensitive by the way.

If I put something before 'CLP' then FTS finds it. After CLP it can't find any word.

Is 'CLP' some kind of magic keyword? 
The language of FTS is neutral, no stop list. 
This script give only 2 records, not 3.

```
create table fts_test (id int identity(1,1) , fts varchar(max))
create  unique index fts_ind on fts_test (id)
insert into fts_test (fts) 
values ('CLP3 365 367'), ('clp3 365 367'), ('365 CLP3 367')
cREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON fts_test (fts) key index fts_ind with stoplist=system;
select * from containstable(fts_test, *, '"365*"')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft support "solved" the problem.

CLP is currency of Chile.

The same behavior can be seen when we use any of the currency codes (Ex: USD, INR, ZAR etc..)."

So after any currency code (capital) and a number after it, then it can't find the following number. If there is word after a currency code than full text search will find it and find the numbers after.

My solution was that I convert to lower case any currency codes in our texts. (Because we don't need this feature and our database's are case insensitive).